# How to disable swagger API documentation from production server in hapijs

Tags: node.js, migration, swagger, hapi.js, production

i am working with hapijs and swagger plugin for API's. I need to push my code on production server but i don't know how exactly i can disable Swagger API Documentation UI without affecting my API's functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://github.com/glennjones/hapi-swagger/blob/master/optionsreference.md) you can turn off the `documentationPage` by setting the options during registering. The documentation also shows how to register the plug-in with options.

```
const hapiSwaggerOptions = {
    info: {
      title: 'Documentation',
      version: '1.0.0',
      description: 'This is the API'
    },
    documentationPage: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
  };

  await server.register([
    Inert,
    Vision,
    { plugin: HapiSwagger, options: hapiSwaggerOptions }, ...]);
```